# How to insert rows into a Room Database from another database file?

Tags: android, sqlite, storage, android-room

My application has a pre-populated Room database which is copied from the "Assets" folder to the data folder of the app in the device when the app is first launched.

Now I am working on how to add rows to the database if the database file already exists. For this I would use the Firebase Storage to hold the "master file" and I would need to download the master file, then i would need to check if all the rows exist in the current file in the application "data" folder and if any rows are missing, then I would insert the missing rows into the database file copied to the device.

My issue is that I don't know where to download the "master file" to and how to access that file's contents. Should I make another DAO and Room Database class to access the file so that I could loop through the contents and add the missing rows like that or is there another way.

Currently I get the file copied with this method

```
    private void loadDbFromFirebase(){
        StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("user database/" + userId + "/locations_table");
        String currentDBPath = "/data/data/"+ getPackageName() + "/databases/locations_table";
        // create file from the database path and convert it to a URI
        File currentDbFile = new File(currentDBPath);
        pathReference.getFile(currentDbFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "download was successful" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "download was not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cursor` and `rawQuery` to access database's content from file:

```
val database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                        context.applicationInfo.dataDir.toString() + "/databases/<database_name>",
                        null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY)

val cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from tableName", null)
cursor.use { c ->
    if (c!!.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            val index = c.getColumnIndex(columnName)
            val value = c.getString(index)
         } while (c.moveToNext())
     }
}
```

I made some demo app https://github.com/YablokovDmitry/DatabaseView/